# How to spec a GENERATED NUMRANGE?

Tags: postgresql, ddl

The GENERATED clauses below all fail to compile in psql, w/ ERROR 42601

What is the correct syntax ? (or are GENERATED NUMRANGEs not supported ?)

```
CREATE TABLE lh  (
   l   NUMERIC,
   h   NUMERIC,

 --lhr NUMRANGE GENERATED ALWAYS AS  numrange(l,h)                    STORED
 --lhr NUMRANGE GENERATED ALWAYS AS  (l,h)::NUMRANGE                  STORED
 --lhr NUMRANGE GENERATED ALWAYS AS '(l,h)'::NUMRANGE                 STORED
 --lhr NUMRANGE GENERATED ALWAYS AS  (l::NUMERIC,h:NUMERIC)           STORED
   lhr NUMRANGE GENERATED ALWAYS AS  (l::NUMERIC,h:NUMERIC)::NUMRANGE STORED
);
```

Comment: Intent is to locate write-once logic in DDL

Comment: The problem is defining a `numrange` will not enforce write-once logic. It is correct that you cannot update the generated column, but updating the columns it is built upon causes the Postgres to regenerate it.  See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=417b626e1f7d5dfeae00697d0da166cf).  Enforcing write-once requires a trigger.

Comment: Yes, thanks, appreciate the point, but in business rules that drive the app, h & l will never change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
CREATE TABLE lh  (
   l   NUMERIC,
   h   NUMERIC,
   lhr NUMRANGE GENERATED ALWAYS AS  (numrange(l,h)) STORED
);
```

You need to include the expression in `()`.

Not sure why you would as it just duplicates existing data that could be just as easily included in query as `numrange(l,h) AS lhr`.

Comment: Thanks!;  

Yes redundant, but 'hlr' is at very foundation of a db app, so prefer reusing 3-char identifier vs running/typing "numrange(l,h) AS lhr" in all the blocks that will use it.

Comment: ( 'lhr', NOT 'hlr' )

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using the range as a `SELECT` convenience, use as `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW lh_range AS
SELECT l, h, numrange(l, h) AS lhr
FROM lh
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d594a4/1).

Comment: Yes, makes sense, thx.
Any reason not to make the view MATERIALIZED ? -- there will be a large number of relations built on top.

Comment: Yes, you could `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW`, which would execute faster, but it won't automatically be refreshed when new rows are added to the base table. However, I wouldn't expect the performance hit to be much. The space saving in row size of the base table may be significant enough to compensate for the generation of numranges on the fly. I would test all approaches (extra column, view, materialized view) and compare performance.